# WSO2 API Manager error in Adding user via SCIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity server and I have tried to create user via SCIM.I am getting the below error.
I have tried it and it was working earlier.Recent change was installing CA signed certificate.Not sure if it has any relation.

```
{
  "Errors": [
    {
      "description": "Error in adding the user: mytestuser to the user store. Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name mytestuser",
      "code": "500"
    }
  ]
} 

In the logs i can see , 

ID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-21 03:24:39,797] ERROR {org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint} -  Internal server error while creating new resource. 
org.wso2.charon.core.exceptions.CharonException: Error in adding the user: mytestuser to the user store. Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name mytestuser
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:179)
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.


    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name mytestuser
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1339)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:173)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:158)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you post the commands/code you use?

Comment: Nothing much. Its just a post to the wso2/scim/Users API of wso2 Idenity server

Comment: ok, it´s a problem with the new CA self signed certificate you use in your .jks. can you try with a new installation and before running it, chage the jks?

Comment: I am not in a position to revert it back..